# How do I use TcpStream split across 2 threads with async?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am trying to use the read and write of a tcp stream in different threads. This is what I currently have:

```
use tokio::prelude::*;
use tokio::net::TcpStream;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("localhost:8080").await?;
    let (mut read, mut write) = stream.split();

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            let mut buf = [0u8; 32];
            read.read(&mut buf).await.unwrap();
            println!("{}", std::str::from_utf8(&buf));
        }
    });

    Ok(())
}
```

Im going to use another thread for the write. My problem is that I get the error that 'stream' is dropped while still borrowed.

Comment: How did you end up using the write in a different thread? Trying to get this work - or potentially return the whole connection so I can get it later - not working out the way I hoped haha. Any tips?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That happens due to the method signature of [`Tokio::split`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.21/tokio/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.split), as you can see it takes `&mut self`, so its part cannot be used in a `tokio::spawn` future argument due to the `'static` bound. So, this is exactly what the error says.

What you are searching is [`tokio::io::split`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.21/tokio/io/fn.split.html). [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=632bd3b6ebfa906296976a4324fea124)

```
use tokio::prelude::*;
use tokio::net::TcpStream;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("localhost:8080").await?;
    let (mut read, mut write) = tokio::io::split(stream);

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            let mut buf = [0u8; 32];
            read.read(&mut buf).await.unwrap();
            println!("{:?}", std::str::from_utf8(&buf));
        }
    });

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-i-have-to-use-tokio-tcpstream-split-for-concurrent-read-writes/47755/3
And it suggests to use `into_split` it is more efficient.

`tokio::io::split` uses a `Mutex` which `into_split` apparently does not have (specific to `TcpStream`)